# Display turns off for 1-2 seconds after disconnecting the power

Tags: windows-10, thinkpad, display-settings

My laptop is Lenovo Thinkpad T470s, Core i5 2.50 GHz processor, ram: 8 GB, OS: windows 10 home. 
When I disconnect the charger from the laptop the display turns off for 1-3 seconds and then turns on again. Who can I stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed the same thing on mine and learned it's because the refresh rate is flickering from 60hz to lower (usually 50hz) when moving to battery off AC power.

It's a well documented behavior dating back to XP at [Lenovo](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-11e-Windows-E-and-Edge/Display-screen-flickers-blinks-goes-blank-or-black-when-AC-power/ta-p/391871) and [Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-2979570/laptop-screen-flickers-unplugged.html) and I was happy to learn **it wasn't a failing laptop and relieved it's behavior by design.**

**No unsaved work/document is lost by this downstepping /flickering.**

A fix is to manually downgrade the Display Refresh Rate in the Advanced properties of the display to 50hz before unplugging, but it takes longer to change the setting than just unplugging and letting the system adjust itself.

Comment: I changed my refresh rate to 48Hz and it is gone. Thank you